# Import data from python to excel

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to parse data from the sec website in python 3.x and to imported it to a csv file. Evryting here works its just that I want to import the data to a specific sheet in a specific xlsm file, is it possible?

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
base_url = r"https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK"

CIK = "0001413329"

json_index = ".json"

url = base_url + CIK + json_index

content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_dict = content.json()

json_key = json_dict['facts']['us-gaap']

file_location = "/Users/eddykwiter/Desktop/Dummy dcf/json.xlsx"
f = open(file_location, "w")
header = "name,date,value,filling period,form"
f.write(header)
f.write("\n")

for i in json_key.keys():
    labels = json_key[i]['units']
    for k in labels.keys():
        try:
            units = labels['USD']
            for e in range(len(units)):
                try:
                    dates = units[e]['end']
                except:
                    dates = ""
                try:
                    values = units[e]['val']
                except:
                    values = ""
                try:
                    filling_period = units[e]['fp']
                except:
                    filling_period = ""
                try:
                    form = units[e]['form']
                except:
                    form = ""
                ligne = str(i)+","+str(dates) +","+str(values)+","+str(filling_period)+","+str(form)
                f.write(ligne)
                f.write("\n")
        except: Exception
        pass

f.close()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should install Pandas excel package:

> pip install xlrd

Then, you can use this line to save your data

> 'filename'.to_excel('path', index = False)